# Why am I getting a "Name error" for a variable that was defined beforehand?

Tags: python, generator, counter, try-except

Not sure why I am getting a `name error` for variable `c15k` when `c15k` is defined beforehand. I have tried putting the entire code in a "try except" statement without success. The goal is to run the last few functions at the end of the code on a `dataframe` column that will change in size based on my filtering. Hence the `c15k, c30k...` in the `try` statement to cover multiple scenarios. Any help is appreciated.

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

try:
    outputs = chunks(df['Delay Comment_clean2'] ,15000)
    c15k,c30k,c45k,c60k,c75k,c90k,c105k,c120k,c135k,c150k,c165k,c180k,c195k,c210k,c225k,c240k,c255k,c270k,c285k,c300k,c315k,c330k = next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs)
    
except:
    pass

def my_tokenizer(text):
    return text.split() if text != None else []

fin = []
def combine (groups):
    for i in groups:
        tokens = i.map(my_tokenizer).sum()
        for j in tokens:
            fin.append(j)
    return fin

from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(combine(c15k))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HECTOR~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13824/4101072889.py in <module>
      1 from collections import Counter
----> 2 counter = Counter(combine(c15k))
      3 # counter.most_common(10)

NameError: name 'c15k' is not defined
```

Comment: are you sure `ck15` is defined? Because it is captured in a `try - except` block and you except does not notify you when the operation fails.

Comment: If the list reference passed to *chunks()* contains fewer than 22 elements, a StopIteration exception will be raised and your attempted assignments to *c15k* etcetera will fail

Comment: @3DspatialUser thanks. Is the `c15k..... = next(outputs)....` not the way you define c15k? and should it not be defined within the `try` statement?

Comment: I om not sure what `outputs` is, but I am guessing that there is an error in that part of the code. You can remove the `try` statement since the code will fail if the `try` statement fails. I would recommend to only use a `try` statement if you can capture the error or if you can deal with a failed `try` block (i.e. you do not need the variable).

Comment: It's *generally* fine to define variables like that… The problem is that *something* within that `try` block fails, and thus the creation of those variables is failing, **and you're suppressing the error message with `except`, so you're not even seeing it.**

Comment: To spell this out clearly: remove the `try..except` around your variable assignment to **see the actually relevant error that's occurring**, then go from there…

Answer (score 1):

Since you have put your assignment in a `try/except` block you will not be notified when your assignment of c15k (and other variables) fail.

You could add something as simple as a `print()` in the `except` body to alert you of anything going wrong in the `try` body.

```py
try:
    outputs = chunks(df['Delay Comment_clean2'] ,15000)
    c15k,c30k,c45k,c60k,c75k,c90k,c105k,c120k,c135k,c150k,c165k,c180k,c195k,c210k,c225k,c240k,c255k,c270k,c285k,c300k,c315k,c330k = next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs), next(outputs)
    
except:
    print("Assignment failed")
```

**Edit:**
As is seen in the below comment it should be noted that this is generally not a good way to use `try/except`. Since you are using variables defined in the `try`-block you will get errors pushed forward. Obfuscating the real problem being variable assignment in the `try`-block.
In your case getting the error thrown at the point of variable assignment would have been much more efficient.

`try/except` is best used when you want to handle errors in a special way, or if there are elements of your code you can accept not to run but the rest can continue as usual. (In your case if `chunks(df['Delay Comment_clean2'] ,15000)` does not run or if `c15k` is not assigned the rest of your script does not fulfill any purpose.)

Comment: The best kind of "alert" would really be an *uncaught exception*, which would also prevent the last line from running, because its precondition failed…

Comment: Absolutely. I will update the answer to add this, in general this is why you dont do try/except without very good reason.